# UI Toolkit в юнити отображается по-разному в геймвью и симуляторе

Tags: unity3d, ui

После нескольких дней борьбы с UI Toolkit я просто не знаю, что делать. Моя проблема: У меня есть сцена, камера и игровой вид из симулятора, который не соответствует UIDocument Выглядит это следующим образом:

Вид билдера и игры:
[image: Вид билдера и игры]

Настройки Visual Element:
[image: Настройки Visual Element]

Настройки кнопки
[image: Настройки кнопки]

Но геймвью:
[image: Игра]

Если я создам UI для вида из "Игры", то когда я соберу проект, все просто сломается?

Игра:
[image: Игра]

Я изначально хотел, чтобы мой UI подстраивался под размер конкретного устройства, но этого не происходит. Я пытался разобраться с этим самостоятельно, я изменял настройки камеры, панели настроек, пытался изменить настройки элементов (я устанавливал формат пикселей, процентов, также использовал абсолютное позиционирование и относительное), но ничего из этого не дало мне желаемого результата. Я пытался искать в документации, в некоторых видео на youtube, просто пытался искать похожую проблему в интернете, но не помогло. Также я попробовал демо-проект Unity "King crushers", который работает именно так, как я хочу в своем проекте, только я не понял, как он устроен.

В итоге я не знаю, что делать, UIBuilder просто не работает. Может быть, я упускаю какие-то базовые понятия?

Comment: `King Crushers` конечно отвратителен, черт ногу сломит, но `Panel Settings` я там увидал.

Comment: `UI ToolKit` не та штука с которой можно базово разобраться по ходу дела и пользоваться не погружаясь. Лучше используй стандартный `UI`.